# Given 2 number arrays, print the cartesian product given that the condition that they should be printed in increasing order

Tags: c

So i was trying to do this exercise but i cant seem to find a good way to write the condition.

The exercise goes like this:

We are given 2 matrixes v1 and v2 and we should build a function that should print the cartesian product of these 2 matrixes with the only condition being that the sum of the 2 coordinates should be lower than the next value so you need to sort them in increasing order

```
v1= {1,2,3};
v2= {3,4,5,6};
```

the result should be: :

```
(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (1,5), (3,3), (1,6), (2,4), (2,5),
(3,4) (2,6), (3,5), (3,6)
```

This is what i have done for now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void prodCartOrd(int *v1, int d1, int *v2, int d2) ;
int main()
{
int v1[] = {1,2,3};
int v2[] = {3,4,5,6};
prodCartOrd(v1, 3, v2, 4);
return 0;
}
 void prodCartOrd(int *v1, int d1, int *v2, int d2)
{    
int sum=0,i=0,j=0;
int a;
for(i=0;i<d1;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<d2;j++)
   {

       if((v1[i]+v2[j])<=(v1[i+1]+v2[j]) || (v1[i]+v2[j])<=(v1[i]+v2[j+1]))
       {
           printf("(%d,%d)",v1[i],v2[j]);
           sum=0;
       }
   }
   }

}
```

Comment: You're example of correct output has, `(1,6), (2,4), ...` but `(1, 6)` is less than `(2, 4)` according to your definition.

Comment: @lurker is it maybe because im looking just one number ahead? Ig that must be it

Comment: Your logic at the very least is incomplete. You defined `sum` but only ever set it to 0 and never use it. Looks like you had something in mind for it but didn't finish. Your code currently would not print all of the tuples because it skips tuples that don't meet your `if` condition. Also, you didn't mention this, but it appears that the two input arrays are assumed each to be already in ascending order? Otherwise, you'd definitely have to do this in two passes, not one.

Comment: I do not think there is a clean way to do this with a simple two-dimensional iteration. If we visualize the Cartesian product as a rectangular matrix formed from the two vectors and consider printing the elements in order, the “current position” in that order forms a sort of jagged diagonal line through that matrix—it is in some position in the first column, some other weakly higher position in the second column, some other weakly higher position in the third column, and so on. Those positions advance depending on arbitrary values in the vectors; there is not a clean expression for them…

Comment: … The import of that is you either need multiple counters to track them all or you have to reconstruct each position as you go back and forth searching for the next element to output. Certainly simple brute force solutions are available. Another alternative is to generate all the elements of the product and sort them. What material was covered in your course recently? If it addressed sorting, then write a sorting solution. If it has not reached that point yet, then write a “brute force” solution.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I fount another way to do it. I fount the max and min values possible. then did a while loop while(min<=max) and did a for loop inside with the if statement saying if(v1[i]+v2[j]== min) print the values then increase the min value. It worked.